# req.body Gives Undefined in a middleware function before a multer function

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I'm working on a project where there will be a section called activity that contains a title, description, flex direction, bunch of images - Using GridFsBucket - and other staff .. so i'm trying to send the Parent activity data first, then send the images as chuncks and save each image's data in a different collection so i can find it with it's data .. so i'm using the saving PARENT Activity collection's data before saving other images so that they can get the activity_id
and here is the function responsible for creating the new document to mongodb to create the parent activity.

```
const createActivity = async (req, res, next) => {
    const { activityTitle, activityDescription, flexDirection } = req.body
    console.log({ activityTitle, activityDescription, flexDirection })
    try {
        let i=1;
        for(i;await Activity.findOne({ordering:i});i++) {
            i = i++
            console.log('activity ' + i)
        }
        const activityLength = await Activity.estimatedDocumentCount()
        if (activityLength >= 10) {
            res.status(400).json({error:"You Can't Add anymore activities."})
            return 0
        }
        console.log(req.body)
        // if (!req.files || req.files.length == 0) {
        //     res.status(400).json({error: 'You must Upload at least an image'})
        //     return 0
        // }
        const activity = await Activity.create({ activityTitle, activityDescription, flexDirection, activity_ordering:i })
        console.log(activity)
        next()
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(400).json({error: err})
    }
}
```

When i send the data using postman agent as below

[Postman Request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G6OQt.png)

it gives an error that the activityTitle,Description and flexDirection ( which im requesting from the body are undefined and required ) ( req.body is undefined or null )

and here's the route as needed to be:

```
router.post('/create-activity', createActivity, uploadNewActivity.array('create-activity', 10), async (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.files)
    try {
        res.json({files: req.files})
    } catch (err) {
        res.json({error: err})
    }
})
```

**Here is the multer middleware**

```
const CreateActivityStorage = new GridFsStorage({
    url:process.env.MONGO_URI_WEBSITE,
    file: (req, file) => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            crypto.randomBytes(16, async (err, buf) => {
                if (err) {
                    reject(err)
                }
                try {
                    // Get PARENT Activity 
                    const {activityTitle, activityDescription, flexDirection} = req.body
                    const activity = await Activity.findOne({activityTitle: activityTitle, activityDescription: activityDescription, flexDirection: flexDirection})

                    // Start Assigning data to each image
                    const filename = `${activity.activityTitle}-${file.originalname}`
                    let i=1;
                    for(i;await ActivityImage.findOne({activity_id:activity.id ,ordering:i});i++) {
                        i = i++
                        console.log('activity image ' + i)
                    }
                    const imageUrl = `/activity-api/activity-image/display/${filename}`

                    // Check if Image Exists
                    const imgExists = await ActivityImage.findOne({filename: filename})
                    if (imgExists) {
                        throw Error('This image already exists')
                    }

                    // Check The Number of Images in this activity
                    const activityImageLength = await ActivityImage.estimatedDocumentCount({activity_id: activity.id})
                    if (activityImageLength >= 10) {
                        reject()
                        throw Error("You've reached maximum images")
                    }
                    // Create in json
                    const activityImage = await ActivityImage.create({filename: filename, ordering:i, imageUrl:imageUrl, activity_id:activity.id})
                    // Create in GridFsBucket
                    const fileInfo = {
                        id: activityImage.id,
                        filename: filename,
                        bucketName: 'Activites'
                    }
                    resolve(fileInfo)
                } catch (err) {
                    reject(err)
                }
            })
        })
    }
})
const uploadNewActivity = multer({ storage: CreateActivityStorage })
```

**the gridFsBucketStorage section has nothing to do with it as it doesn't even get to it's part.

**Body Parser is added and i already sent many different data before

**It works when seperating the two requests but it would much better and helpful if it were in one request**

Comment: Your sequence of the middleware is not correct. It should be like this, 
('/create-activity', uploadNewActivity.array('create-activity', 10), createActivity)
Your controller should come after the multer middleware.

Comment: the multer middleware contains assigning activity_id which gets called after being created .. so i need to create the activity first then the upload the image

Comment: Actually for the form-data/multipart requests, Multer separates the req.body and the req.files.
If you are using the multer middleware after the controller, your controller cannot differentiate the req.body and req.file. In simple terms, your controller will get the req.body as null.